# Counting the number of maximal chains in a Hasse Diagram

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, order-theory

Given a Hasse Diagram of a poset, how can we determine all maximal chains? Is there any tried-and-tested algorithm to efficiently compute the answer? [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2013474/counting-the-number-of-maximal-chains-in-a-poset) question deals with the specific case where a set is ordered by the divisibility relation. But how are we to determine the maximal chains of any poset given it's Hasse Diagram?

Any help is appreciated!